# Using RichFaces 4 in a JSF 2.0 application

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to add RichFaces to JSF 2.0 application, but I get this: 
`The requested resource () is not available.` 
That's from Console:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ajax4jsf.Filter
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RichFaces4Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


<!-- Plugging the "Blue Sky" skin into the project -->

<context-param>

   <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>

   <param-value>blueSky</param-value>

</context-param>



<!-- Making the RichFaces skin spread to standard HTML controls -->

<context-param>

      <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>

      <param-value>enable</param-value>

</context-param>



<!-- Defining and mapping the RichFaces filter -->

<filter> 

   <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name> 

   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name> 

   <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class> 

</filter> 



<filter-mapping> 

   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name> 

   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>

   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>

   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>

</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My lib dir:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since RichFaces 4.0 you do not need the `org.ajax4jsf.Filter`. This is also not included in RF 4.0 anymore. Please read the [developer guide for RichFaces 4.0](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/), not the one for RichFaces 3.x or older. For RF 4.0 you do not need to put anything in `web.xml`. Just remove the entire `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I have another problem. The components don't render. For example when I try this demo: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tabPanel.jsf?c=tabPanel&tab=usage i get something like this: "Here is an example of default tab panel with 3 tabs.



 j_id1475365623_57f04a9f j_id1475365623_57f04a9f j_id1475365623_57f04a9f 
 j_id1475365623_57f04a75 j_id1475365623_57f04a75 j_id1475365623_57f04a75 
 j_id1475365623_57f04a6b j_id1475365623_57f04a6b j_id1475365623_57f04a6b 
 
 

«
↓
»
Here is tab #1
"

Comment: That's a different problem. Your initial question was about a `ClassNotFoundException` on the filter. If you have a new problem, please press `Ask Question`. Comments are not the right place to post new questions/answers.